# Rapid Miner - IF statements

Tags: if-statement, rapidminer

I'm having a slight problem with my IF function expression in a generate attribute operator.

Essential this is the functionality I would like the function to have.

```
If VarX contains ".0", then remove this .0, else leave VarX unchanged
```

So far this is the syntax I have for the function expression in Rapid Miner.

```
if(contains(".0",VarX),replace(".0",VarX,""),VarX)
```

However this syntax is not working correctly, as the **".0"** in the data are not being replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter ordering is incorrect.

Try the following

```
if(contains(VarX, ".0"), replace(VarX, ".0", ""),VarX)
```